# Proof of expansion of $e^{ix}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, exponential-function

I am reading *Lévy Processes and Infinitely Divisible Distributions* by Ken-iti Sato and I don't understand how the expansion
$$\tag{1}
e^{iu} = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{(iu)^k}{k!} + \theta\frac{|u|^n}{n!}
$$
for each $u\in\mathbb{R}$ and some $\theta\in\mathbb{C}$ with $|\theta|\leq 1$ is derived in Lemma 8.6.

The proof just states that it follows immediately from the identity

$$\tag{2}
e^{iu} = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{(iu)^k}{k!} + \frac{i^n}{(n-1)!}\int_0^u(u-v)^{n-1}e^{iv}dv\ .
$$

My questions are:

1. Where does identity (2) come from? The Taylor formula for real-valued functions seems to yield this expression if applied to $f(u)=e^{iu}$, but this is not a real-valued function and all versions for complex functions look different. How is the use of the standard Taylor formula justified for functions $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}$ ?
2. How does (1) follow from (2)? I thought about some kind of mean value theorem, but wasn't able to see how the simple expression in (1) can be obtained from the integral in (2).

For my purposes, it would be sufficient to derive the formula for $n=2$, if that makes it easier to explain.

Comment: What does Lemma 8.6 say?

Comment: Are you familiar with Taylor's Theorem?  What happens if you differentiate both sides the identity $n$ times?  Do you see what it is an identity?

Comment: It just states (1). The full proof ist just "Follows immediately from (2)"

Comment: @MarkViola Yes I know Taylor's theorem but I don't understand your hint. More importantly, I would like to understand how (1) can be obtained from (2)

Comment: Partial answer: (2) looks like the [Schlömilch Remainder](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SchloemilchRemainder.html).

Comment: @KurtG. But isn't that a remainder of the Taylor formula for real-valued functions? Do you have a reference for the proof for complex-valued functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(2) is the Taylor's theorem with integral remainder. Unlike the mean value forms of the theorem, this version of the theorem works for $\mathbb{R}^k$ valued functions because integration of $\mathbb{R}^k$-valued functions is defined component-wise. Here we use $k = 2$, $\mathbb{C} \approx \mathbb{R}^2$.

To get from (2) to (1) you use the fact that the remainder has modulus $\leq \frac{|u|^n}{n!}$.

Comment: Thank you! Can you please explain what you mean by $\mathbb{C}\approx\mathbb{R}$? And why does the remainder have modulus $\leq |u|^n/n!$?

Comment: @Leguan3000 By definition, integration of a complex valued function $h = f + ig$ is defined as $\int h := \int f + i \int g$. That's all I really meant by $\mathbb{C} \approx \mathbb{R}^2$. This means that you can apply the Taylor theorem to $f$ and $g$, and therefore get it for $h$.

Comment: @Leguan3000 To bound the remainder, use $$|\int_0^u(u-v)^{n-1}e^{iv}dv| \leq \int_0^u|(u-v)^{n-1}e^{iv}|dv = \int_0^u|u-v|^{n-1}dv = \dots.$$